# (Python Beginner) adding coordinates together from two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I am working on an exercise where we are adding matrices together. In the dictionaries given, the first number in the key is the row, the second number in the key is the column, and the third number is the value of the given coordinate:

```
matrix1={(2, 2): 5, (1, 2): 4, (0, 1): 2, (0, 0): 1, (1, 1): 3, (2, 3): 6}
matrix2={(0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 4, (2, 0): 6, (2, 3): -6}
```

What code would add them together so that the coordinates/keys that are equal to each other combine and the others just come together for this output:

```
matrix1+2={(0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 2, (1, 1): 3, (1, 2): 7, (1, 3): 4, (2, 0): 6, (2, 2): 5,  (2, 3): 0}
```

Comment: So what is the question ?:)

Comment: What code would add them together so that the coordinates/keys that are equal to each other combine and the others just come together for this output:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can switch the dictionary object to a counter object, add the counters, and then return it to being a dictionary like so. This will do what you desire.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> matrix1 = Counter(matrix1)
>>> matrix2 = Counter(matrix2)
>>> matrix1.update(matrix2)
Counter({(1, 2): 7, (2, 0): 6, (2, 2): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 1): 3, (1, 1): 3, (0, 2): 2, (0, 0): 1, (2, 3): 0})
>>> matrix = dict(matrix1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: 0, matrix2)
for pos, value in matrix1.items():
    d[pos] += value
```